# valgrind on endless program launch by Jenkins: How to stop it?

Tags: c++, jenkins, valgrind

I would like to use valgrind on an endless program - it is a QT program and I cannot stop it when it is running.

The analysis of the program is launched by Jenkins to feed into a Sonar report. However, if I don't kill it, valgrind will not produce a report.

Is there a way to stop valgrind without manual intervention? I tried a Google search but I did not find anything.

Please help me.
Thanks.
Shoxolat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a recent version of Valgrind, you can have leak search and other
functionalities triggered from GDB or from the command line (using vgdb utility,
part of Valgrind).

See e.g. [gdbserver command handling](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-commandhandling) and [memcheck monitor commands](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands)
You can also kill Valgrind using v.kill monitor command

Comment: I actually use valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian on debian squeeze.
I found some post with  vgdb but it's look like that vgdb is not support on 3.6

Comment: Well, as indicated "use a recent version of Valgrind". It is easy to download Valgrind source last release and compile + install locally (under your home dir for example).